# Is working on trunk a good practice?

Tags: branching-and-merging, release-management, trunk

i am working on product in a company. Here i see developers are working directly on trunk which doesn't look like
good practice to me .

**Disadvantage of working on trunk :-**
Reason is  if new client needs our product at some time in future, may be product is not stable.
Another scenario can be if another team needs to develop some feature parallely.  Team will be never be sure about
stablity of trunk code.

**Adavantage :-**
QA team does not have to put double efforts for testing on both Branch and Trunk.

So i am not sure if working on trunk can ever be good strategy ?

Comment: There is no single answer for this question. If you follow the "continuous delivery" - then it's what you're supposed to do. "Team will be never be sure about stablity of trunk code" --- that's why you need tests.

Comment: A _very_ interesting topic, but probably more suitable for http://programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/107884/to-branch-or-not-to-branch and http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/183819/can-branching-ever-be-considered-a-bad-practice

Comment: Variations on this question have been asked and answered ad nauseum on Programmers.SE already. Best to close it here and let people use the search function on Programmers.SE.

Answer (score 0):

There are many workflow define by various source control tool.
I am not sure which source control tool are you using, But truth is every strategy has advantages and disadvantages, Its up to you to choose the best fit for your requirement.

You can even decide the workflow recommended for the VCS you are using.